# compare 2 files and execute commands after matching the patterns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 2 files, say test and test1 with the following values.

test:

```
apple;orange;mkdir /etc/test;cd /etc/test;touch 123;mkdir 1234
banana;orange;cd /etc/test;touch abc;mkdir abcd
grape;lemon;cd /etc/test;touch abcd;mkdir abcde
```

test1:

```
apple;orange;
```

How to compare test1 and test and execute the rest of commands which matches the values?

In this case it should run `mkdir /etc/test;cd /etc/test;touch 123;mkdir 1234`.

Comment: This is a horribly reckless way to handle commands. You need to limit the excepted commands to a handful. Heaven forbid `file` contains `apple;orange;sudo rm -r /; sudo dd of=/dev/sda if=/dev/zero bs=448 count=1` (or some other equally nefarious command)

Comment: hi david , totally understood. here i need only mkdir and cd commands. nothing else

Comment: Good deal -- and then make sure it is writable by no one but you `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your actual Input_file(s) are same as shown samples then following `awk` may help you on same. Also since I don't have permissions to create directory in `/etc` so couldn't test it with given sample.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/\;$/,"");a[$0];next} (($1,$2) in a){$1=$2="";system($0)}' SUBSEP=";" test1  FS=";" test
```

OR(without `SUBSEP`):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/\;$/,"");a[$0];next} (($1";"$2) in a){$1=$2="";system($0)}' test1  FS=";" test
```

Comment: hi ravinder i am getting below error                                                    mkdir: cannot create directory `cd': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/test': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `touch': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `123': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `mkdir': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `1234': File exists

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/test': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `cd': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `/etc/chef': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `touch': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `123': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `mkdir': File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory `1234': File exists

Comment: @gosatriani, even I am too getting same error seems a file named test is already present, but you could run other commands by this script given. Try some basic commands. Also first test the things then only try to run something on `/etc` level please.

Comment: hi ravinder i changed the input format of test to apple;orange;mkdir -p /etc/test && cd /etc/test && touch 123 && mkdir 1234

Comment: @gosatriani, is it working for you now? Could you please let me know on same.

Comment: worked thanks. seems like some issue with semicolon changed to && and worked.

Comment: hi ravinder.. can you please tell me how to master awk ... any documentation or something??

Comment: @gosatriani, 1st is `man awk` then O reially book and then lot of practice on SO, when we help others actually we are helping us to learn :), keep asking, keep sharing knowledge cheers :)